# View event listeners - Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, zepto

I'm wondering if it is possible to view

**1. How many event listeners**

**2. What type of event listener**

On a single web page.

Reason being is because I'm  using `off();` method.

I'm using this **[framework](http://zeptojs.com/)**, which is basically jQuery but not.

Yeah, I'm using off but the even't isn't removing and and I have a feeling there is more than one `eventListener` on the element.

If it is not possible with Javascript, it is possible in the browser?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome has some built in tools. If you open up the element inspector, focus on an element, scroll to the bottom of the right hand column (where the CSS/Metrics/etc are), you should see a drop down section that says Event Listeners. This can help some...

Often I find it easier to just add event listeners to some DOM element via the console and seeing if it responds. Or I throw in debuggers in various places (before setting up the listener, and inside the listener's callback). The problems I usually run into is the selector I think exists doesn't or the event gets bound too early and misses the selector.

Comment: Excellent, I did not realise that was there and provides lot's of information, Thank You.

Answer (score 25):

> *A long time passes...*

I have found something new in Chrome DevTools.

Simple as this in the `console`

```
getEventListeners(yourElement);
```

**Documentation: [https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject)**

Comment: But where is the actual function definition for whatever is listening. I just see a huge object tree. I want to know what exactly is triggered by the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Visual Event bookmarklet: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: There is a chrome extension as well which uses the same code https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim