# Find unknown active event listeners Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, passive-event-listeners

---

### **I would like to find unknown event listeners**

So far I tried to locate all event listeners based on [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795211/view-event-listeners-javascript) but it did not work:

```
getEventListeners(Element);
```

and

```
'Chrome Developer tools > Elements > Event listeners'
```

### Are there other ways to detect active event listeners?

---

The reason for asking this is:

I'm building the [2D breakout game](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) using pure JavaScript based on the tutorial from Mozilla and managed to enhance it with various features and multiple levels.

I have a set of added event listeners and also a function that removes them, so far everything works fine.

***I do not have an event listener for keycode 13(which is the enter key)***

The problem is that if I press the Enter key while the animation is ongoing on the canvas, it changes the behavior with increasing the speed of the ball after each keypress and ultimately it renders a different drawing.

If I don't press the Enter key everything works as intended.

The only event listener that increases the speed is a 'click' event, but that is removed immediately after the function is executed, and it shouldn't interfere with the game.

**The other problem is that through the above-mentioned methods there are no event listeners found, not even the ones I added myself, albeit they still work.**

I could not find anything that relates to that unwanted behavior and I would like to ask if there are other ways to view the active event listeners.

[Here](https://github.com/leonard186/flipTheTiles/blob/master/resources/js/breakout.js) is the code I'm working on

---

[**EDIT:**
After realising that the bug was coming from a `keydown` event, adding `preventDefault()` solved the problem.

However, I'm not sure why did this behaviour occur when there was no `e.keyCode == 13` setup in the first place and why did the `preventDefault()` method solve the issue. 
]

Comment: Could I ask why `getEventListeners` isn't sufficient? Why do you need another way? Does the speedup happen on any key, or just enter? Given you don't have a listener on keyCode === 13, this is indeed strange.

Comment: @DavidsKanal, when I try to use `getEventListeners` on `document` or `canvas` it returns an object tree where I cannot find any of the event listeners. The speedup only happens when I press the Enter Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the bug lays in the `keydown` event handler (`keyDownHandler`). This is what was causing the unexpected behaviour.

The bug disappeared after adding `e.preventDefault();` to `keyDownHandler` function.

**Original:**

```
function keyDownHandler(e) { //on key down
e.keyCode == 37 ? leftPressed = true : null;
e.keyCode == 39 ? rightPressed = true : null;
```

}

**After:**

```
function keyDownHandler(e) { //on key down
e.preventDefault();
e.keyCode == 37 ? leftPressed = true : null;
e.keyCode == 39 ? rightPressed = true : null;
```

**End result:** Nothing happens when pressing the Enter Key

*Credit to **@Joe Fitzsimmons** for pointing me in the right direction*

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the click event is giving focus to giraffe allowing it to be fired with the enter key.  You can try mousedown and preventDefault to keep giraffe from taking focus:

```
giraffe.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 giraffe.classList.remove('pulsate');
        setTimeout(function(){
            giraffe.classList.add('pulsate');
        }, 0);
        yahoo.play();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I tried that but unfortunately, it did not work. I even tried to remove the whole function to see if that has any effect but the bug persists.